# Google App Engine and GCP Load Balancer request inspection

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have an API running in Google App Engine and I want to introspect HTTP POST body to reject poorly formed calls before it hits my API running in app engine.  Is there a way to front an App Engine application whereby I can introspect the URI, the POST body and return a 400 without it actually being processed by my code running in App Engine?  Please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inspect HTTP, then you will need to write a proxy application to do so. Neither the Google Cloud Load Balancer nor App Engine support hooking HTTP requests.

Proxies have the MITM (Man In The Middle) problem in that HTTP traffic is often encrypted. You will not be able to inspect that traffic unless your proxy is the endpoint. If you implement your proxy with Apache or Nginx then you can use the [ModSecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity) project.

Basically, you want to implement a WAF. Google offers [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview) which supports inspecting traffic via Cloud Armor rules.