# How to create a reverse proxy with GCP that analyzes http headers for incoming request?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, reverse-proxy

I need to analize the http headers for incoming requests to knowwhere to redirect those request. I'm using some GCP services like Load Balancing,
however I'm not sure where should I set that re-directioning rules or do I need a microservice or something else that makes that re-directioning.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063136/8016720

Comment: You must have a service that perform the routing that you want (NGINX or custom service). Google Cloud Load Balancer doesn't allow you to configure that